# Running Raygun.io with Angular Universal

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-universal, raygun.io

I'm adding `Raygun.io` APM to our Angular 8 app with Angular Universal.

It is known that `raygun.io` has a client side javascript library and to add this to a Angular with Universal, DOM window API must be created. This can be done using domino npm using this code below:

There is also an installation guide for Angular via npm called `raygun4js` however the problem still exists.

```
// Domino for defining Windows API in SSR 
(found @ https://www.npmjs.com/package/domino )

const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync(index.html).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);

global['window'] = win; // will be used for NodeJS to read Window API
global['document'] = win.document;
```

*domino creates a window api and sets it to a global called win.
After adding this line to an NPM project `server.ts`, build and run command - an exception is found:

```
  Raygun.Utilities = raygunUtilityFactory(window, Raygun);
  ^

ReferenceError: raygunUtilityFactory is not defined
```

This roots that a `raygunUtilityFactory` function is not defined within window API. Looking inside `raygun.js` in Github

```
window.raygunUtilityFactory = function(window, Raygun) {
  var rg = {
    getUuid: function() {
      function _p8(s) {
        var p = (Math.random().toString(16) + '000000000').substr(2, 8);
        return s ? '-' + p.substr(0, 4) + '-' + p.substr(4, 4) : p;
      }

 // more code.....
```

Question is, how can NodeJS read `raygunUtilityFactory` function during build if it can't find it in window API?

UPDATE: I tried to do this on a smaller project but it seems that even its document for installing `raygun.io` doesn't include procedures for `Angular Universal`. It basically can't detect window API using `domino`

```
  Raygun.Utilities = raygunUtilityFactory(window, Raygun);
  ^

ReferenceError: raygunUtilityFactory is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Setting `Raygun` js as a global object and referencing it to a declared variable inside a service.

Reference: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af

```
declare var rg4js: any;
```

*place this inside your service or your main component ts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  !function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h){a.RaygunObject=e,a[e]=a[e]||function(){
  (a[e].o=a[e].o||[]).push(arguments)},f=b.createElement(c),g=b.getElementsByTagName(c)[0],
  f.async=1,f.src=d,g.parentNode.insertBefore(f,g),h=a.onerror,a.onerror=function(b,c,d,f,g){
  h&&h(b,c,d,f,g),g||(g=new Error(b)),a[e].q=a[e].q||[],a[e].q.push({
  e:g})}}(window,document,"script","//cdn.raygun.io/raygun4js/raygun.min.js","rg4js");
</script>
```

*add this to your index.html or download and add it to your project.

Do take note that the `raygun` script should be referenced as rg4js.
Angular will automatically know that the rg4js inside your TS file is reference to your `raygun` script tag.

-- I'm now able to see the crash reporting and the pulse monitoring inside our client dashboard. However, I noticed that all client side errors logs are not caught. I'm still researching way to send these unhandled errors - starting with `windows.onerror`.

Answer (score 0):

Good to hear you have figured out part of the solution!

AngularJS captures a lot of errors under the hood automatically and to properly capture errors you will need to register your own [angular error handler](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler) and when the callback is fired you can use the [Raygun4JS send method](https://github.com/MindscapeHQ/raygun4js#usage) to send the message to Raygun.

```
export class RaygunErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(e: any) {
    rg4js('send', {
      error: e,
    });
  }
}
```

Raygun has a little bit of [angular documentation](https://raygun.com/documentation/language-guides/javascript/crash-reporting/angularjs/) but can't import raygun4js via npm for Angular Universal (as per your discovery) so you will need to modify the examples shown. That said they should provide a good starting point.

Comment: They had an update for Angular 2+ and it works for most cases but if you're using Universal, adding a custom handler for error will not work and will mostly display an error